# How to group anagrams in a string into an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, hashmap

I want to group anagrams in ruby from a given string and the result should be an array containing arrays of anagram groups like
Given String: "scream cars for four scar creams"
here cars and scar are anagrams(made by same characters)
and the result should be [[cars, scar], ['for'], ['four'], ['creams', 'scream']]

I tried like this but it always returning an empty hash, from which i want to extract the values.

```
s = "scream cars for four scar creams"
anagrams_hash = Hash.new([])
words = s.split
words.each {|word| anagrams_hash[word.chars.sort.join] << word}
```

but anagrams_hash doesn't changing after running my code and remains as `{}`

Comment: this returns array, not hash

Comment: @andreydeineko The question concerns the `anagrams_hash` and not the return value of this snippet as such, but you are right that if this were a method then the line `anagrams_hash` should be added to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't assign the resulting array back to `anagrams_hash`, i.e., you take the array from the hash and then you append the word to that array, but never write the resulting array back to the hash. This causes a problem when the key does not exist in the hash and you get the default element instead. The fix would be, e.g.,

```
words.each {|word| anagrams_hash[word.chars.sort.join] += [ word ] }
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation and helping me solve this problem

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it your way, then Stefan is right. But I don't understand the purpose of `join` in your code. Also, you don't have to manually iterate over a hash. There is a more Rubish way.

```
"scream cars for four scar creams".split.group_by{|w| w.chars.sort}.values
#=> [["scream", "creams"], ["cars", "scar"], ["for"], ["four"]]
```

Comment: Yes your solution is simple and concise thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare your hash using the block syntax:

```
anagrams_hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
```